# Trigger a Cloudwatch alarm from a SQS message with high ReceiveCount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs, cloudwatch-alarms

Is it possible to trigger a Cloudwatch alarm based on one of the messages in a SQS queue having a high ReceiveCount?

For example, this message has been received 611 without being successfully processed and deleted from the queue.

Ideally i'd like an alert if a message has been received 10 times.

I can't see a metric that would expose this informatio/ based on [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html)

[image: SQS message with high receive count]